# Is it normal to have cdcdcdcd in stacks on msvc debug mode

Tags: c++, memory, visual-c++

I have some crashes and I suspect this is due to some stack corruption.Dump memory of the stack with `dd` in windbg I have some special values:

```
0:000> dd esp 00000084`67b9fd30
00000084`67b96cc0  67b96d00 00000084 89194aa8 00007ff7
00000084`67b96cd0  cdcdcdcd cdcdcdcd cccccccc cccccccc
00000084`67b96ce0  cccccccc cccccccc cccccccc cccccccc
00000084`67b96cf0  cccccccc cccccccc cccccccc cccccccc
00000084`67b96d00  67b96d40 00000084 89194978 00007ff7
00000084`67b96d10  cdcdcdcd cdcdcdcd cccccccc cccccccc
00000084`67b96d20  cccccccc cccccccc cccccccc cccccccc
00000084`67b96d30  cccccccc cccccccc cccccccc cccccccc
00000084`67b96d40  67b96e10 00000084 891a942f 00007ff7
00000084`67b96d50  cdcdcdcd cdcdcdcd 67b96dd8 00000084
```

As far as I know, `0xcdcdcdcd cdcdcdcd` is special values on heap when program is compiled with debug option on msvc.

If this is a abnormal situation, what is the common reasons for this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127386/in-visual-studio-c-what-are-the-memory-allocation-representations has a list of the special values. You might be taking an uninitialised heap value and assigning it to a local variable - i.e. `int local_var = *heap_ptr`

Comment: @JamesPicone So it is a abnormal situation to have such values on stack?I mean it is an error at least.

Comment: No, it is not abnormal.

Comment: @Eljay Can you explain it a little bit? it's not some random value, I have many such values on my stack.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When and why will an OS initialise memory to 0xCD, 0xDD, etc. on malloc/free/new/delete?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/370195/when-and-why-will-an-os-initialise-memory-to-0xcd-0xdd-etc-on-malloc-free-new)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`0xCCCCCCCC` marks uninitialized stack memory, so it's normal for it to be on the stack. It shouldn't ever be read by your program though since that means you're reading uninitialized memory. `0xCDCDCDCD` marks uninitialized heap memory, so having it on the stack shows that you've probably read uninitialized heap memory somewhere and copied it to the stack which isn't good.